# How to execute two completion blocks in a single function and pass the data of the completion block to next view controller?

Tags: swift, firebase, closures, snapshot

This is my database structure:

[image: This is the database structure]

I'm using a function with closure, performing two completion blocks and store the data in two separate arrays. Once I get the data I want to pass the data to next view controller into different variables, but instead I'm getting same value for both arrays.

```
@IBAction func GoToAnswerPage(_ sender: Any) {

    self.getData(refe:JoinCodeTextField.text!) { (array) in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"JoinToAnswerPage",sender:array)
    }

}

func getData(refe: String, completion: @escaping (([Any]) -> ())) {
    var questionArray = [Any]()
    var answerArray = [Any]()
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://pollapp-30419.firebaseio.com/").child("Questions/\(refe)/")
    ref.child("Question_And_Options").observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{
            questionArray.append(value)
        }
        completion(questionArray)
    })
    ref.child("Answer_Key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{
            answerArray.append(value)
        }
        completion(answerArray)
    })
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let joinViewController = segue.destination as? JoinAnswerViewController
        else {
            return
    }
    joinViewController.answers = sender as! [String]
    joinViewController.options = sender as! [String]
}
```

On the next view controller.

```
var options = [Any]()
var answers = [Any]()
```

This is the output I'm getting:

> `answers-["Test Q-1", "Test A-1", "Test A-2"]`
>
> `questions-["Test Q-1", "Test A-1", "Test A-2"]`
>
> `answers-["Test A-1"]`
>
> `questions-["Test A-1"]`

Instead I should get:

> `questions-["Test Q-1", "Test A-1", "Test A-2"]`
>
> `answers-["Test A-1"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completion handler will be called twice, once for "answers" and once for "questions".  They could come in either order, so you should pass an additional `type` in the completion to know which you have received.  Use a `[String : [Any]]` dictionary to collect the two arrays, and call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` when you've received both arrays and stored them in the dictionary `arrays`.

In `prepare(for:sender:)` unpack the `sender` dictionary and assign the values:

```
@IBAction func GoToAnswerPage(_ sender: Any) {

    var arrays = [String : [Any]]()

    self.getData(refe: JoinCodeTextField.text!) { (array, type) in

        arrays[type] = array

        if arrays.count == 2 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"JoinToAnswerPage",sender: arrays)
        }
    }

}

func getData(refe: String, completion: @escaping (([Any], String) -> ())) {
    var questionArray = [Any]()
    var answerArray = [Any]()
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://pollapp-30419.firebaseio.com/").child("Questions/\(refe)/")
    ref.child("Question_And_Options").observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{
            questionArray.append(value)
        }
        completion(questionArray, "question")
    })
    ref.child("Answer_Key").observeSingleEvent(of: .value,with: { snapshot in
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{
            answerArray.append(value)
        }
        completion(answerArray, "answer")
    })
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let joinViewController = segue.destination as? JoinAnswerViewController
        else {
            return
    }

    guard let arrays = sender as? [String : [Any]],
          let answers = arrays["answer"] as? [String],
          let questions = arrays["question"] as? [String]
        else { return }

    joinViewController.answers = answers
    joinViewController.options = questions
}
```

---

**Note:**  When the user presses a button, they should get an immediate response.  Since you are loading the data from the network, there may be a delay making the user wonder if anything is happening.  It would be better to pass `JoinCodeTextField.text!` to `JoinAnswerViewController` and let it load the question/answer data.  `JoinAnswerViewController` could display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` (spinner) while the data is loading to let the user know the data is coming.  Once you have both arrays, you can set up the `JoinAnswerViewController`.